# python: json.dumps can't handle utf-8?

Tags: python, json

Below is the test program, including a Chinese character:

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
import json

j = {"d":"中", "e":"a"}
json = json.dumps(j, encoding="utf-8")

print json
```

Below is the result, look the json.dumps convert the utf-8 to the original numbers!

```
{"e": "a", "d": "\u4e2d"}
```

Why this is broken? Or anything I am wrong?

Comment: first of all : __don't name your var json__ you will not be able to access json lib anymore after that , second of all nothing is broken, beside the default json encoding is utf-8 so you don't have to add it in dumps() args .

Comment: if I can accept it to turn binary utf-8 data into "\u4e2d", how can I convert it back to binary utf-8 in the javascript, which is the client receiving this data?

Comment: have you try it ?, i mean send it like that to the browser i think if you're using a sophisticate javascript lib it will know what to do with it.

Comment: See [my answer to How do I write JSON data to a file in Python?](http://stackoverflow.com/a/37795053/562769)

Answer (score 30, accepted):

You should read [json.org](http://json.org). The complete JSON specification is in the white box on the right.

There is nothing wrong with the generated JSON. Generators are allowed to genereate either UTF-8 strings or plain ASCII strings, where characters are escaped with the `\uXXXX` notation. In your case, the Python `json` module decided for escaping, and `中` has the escaped notation [`\u4e2d`](http://codepoints.net/U+4e2d).

By the way: Any conforming JSON interpreter will correctly unescape this sequence again and give you back the actual character.

Answer (score 61):

Looks like valid JSON to me. If you want `json` to output a string that has non-ASCII characters in it then you need to pass `ensure_ascii=False` and then encode manually afterward.

Answer (score 9):

Use simplejson with the mentioned options:

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
import simplejson as json

j = {"d":"中", "e":"a"}
json = json.dumps(j, ensure_ascii=False, encoding="utf-8")

print json
```

Outs:

```
{"e": "a", "d": "中"}
```

Comment: There is no need for this; the standard library `json` module offers the same options.

Comment: if python 2 use `import simplejson as json ` for python 3 use `import json`

Comment: No, that is wrong; `json` [has been available in the standard library since 2.6, and has had these options the entire time](https://docs.python.org/2.6/library/json.html#basic-usage).