# Basic Python encoding

Tags: python, encoding

I have a file which is simple:

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

a = u'Alegría'
print a
print {'a': a}
```

The output is:

```
Alegría
{'a': u'Alegr\xeda'}
```

Why I am getting that instead of:

```
Alegría
{'a': u'Alegría'}
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: Printing a dictionary uses `repr` instead of just printing the raw contents of the strings.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`dict`'s string representation calls `repr` on keys and values, and `repr` tries its best to make a string representation that you can paste in any file or interpreter, with or with an encoding declared, and get the object back.

Your string is fine, it's just a safe representation.

Comment: I was trying to print that to a file by serializing it to JSON. I guess JSON works in a similar way as repr, since I was getting the ugly {'a': u'Alegr\xeda'} printed to the file. Would you know how to serialize that to {'a': u'Alegría'}? Thanks

Edit: I think I found the answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4184108/python-json-dumps-cant-handle-utf-8

Comment: JSON shouldn't contain non-ASCII characters, and string representation of python dicts are not valid JSON. A JSON object with key `a` and value `Alegría` would look like this: `{"a": "Alegr\u00eda"}`. Why does it matter to you what the serialized format looks like? You `json.dump` it on one end, `json.load` it on the other and get exactly what you dumped.

Comment: I want to dump the dict to a file, then edit it by hand and finally load it with JavaScript.

It would be nice to have it nicely printed in the JSON file so I can easily edit it since it is more readable.